# Clustered Environment on RedHat/CentOs - Apache, PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, centos, cluster-computing

I need to setup environment for large service, written in `PHP 5`. I need all services to be set up in clustered environment (load-balanced and/or failover cluster). What solution is most popular and most used today on RedHat Enterprise / Centos?

I think there should be some proxy server for Apache (to serve cached data if possible) and MySqL in clustered environment (but I don't really like `MySQL Cluster edition`, since it uses its own table engine with some unacceptable limitations).

I'm rather looking for some solution that can be applied on system level (`CentOS/RHEL` in my case). Do you have any tips where to start and what to use?

Comment: My first tip is not to use MySQL. If you're looking for high scalability and superior performance, you probably [want to check out Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/). I'd probably even steer away from Apache and move towards nginx or lighttpd.

Comment: Is this 100% compatible with MySQL? If not, it's useless for me. Also, my application is not so large to use nosql solutions.